# When can boundedness be characterized topologically in Metric spaces?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let H be a separable and infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. Is every closed subset of H homeomorphic 
to some closed and bounded subset of H?

Comment: It would suffice to know whether H is homoeomorphic to a
closed bounded subset of itself.

Comment: You may want to reprhase the title to actually match the question.

Comment: to Robin Chapman: Actually, as you can see from the response below,
your question has an affirmative answer-since it has been proved
that H is homeomorphic to its own closed unit ball. But I still 
do not see how I can use this result to prove that my question has
an affirmative answer (or that it has a negative answer).

Comment: I will never understand why it took me so long to see that your
question is equivalent to mine but I finally do see it. Thanks
for teaching me something about homeomorphisms that I once learned
but had somehow forgotten.

Answer (score 11):

It is an old result of Klee saying that the infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is homeomorphic with both its unit sphere and its closed unit ball. See e.g. http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1961-67-03/S0002-9904-1961-10589-2/S0002-9904-1961-10589-2.pdf , and the references therein.

Comment: Also, H is homeomorphic with any closed half-space of it, which is the reason why a "C<sup>0</sup> Hilbert manifold with boundary" is in fact a C<sup>0</sup> Hilbert manifold without boundary. 